# Place element on top of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place a DIV with the same dimensions as the blue box, above the blue box :D

[image]

I know it's possible by making the blue box relative, the put the DIV inside it with absolute position at position 0,0.

But is there any way to do this without altering the CSS of the blue box, and without placing it inside it?

I want the DIV that goes over to be at the end of the document body.

Comment: See here http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Without altering the CSS? Of course not.

Comment: I would usually do this sort of thing with Javascript. Since the position of the blue could be arbitrary. Would you accept a jQuery answer?

Comment: I find jQuery to be far overkill. You can place a secondary blue box _above_ the original blue box _without_ altering the original blue box. Very simple, look at my answer. Also, @Alex post your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.blue-box {
    ...stuff here...
}

div.other-blue-box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /* z-index must be greater than the z-index of div.blue-box */
    top: <location of the div.blue-box>; /* must correspond with the top position of the div.blue-box */
    left: <location of the div.blue-box>; /* must correspond with the left position of the div.blue-box */
}
```

By setting `position : absolute` to the new `div`, it will go where you tell it to regardless of other elements on the page. The `z-index` makes sure that it gets put *above* the original blue box. It does not matter where you place your new blue box in the DOM, as long as it has absolute position and a greater zeta index than other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no way to change the placement of the divs without altering the css. Scratch positioning and try floats and clears.